# How to add assembly reference in aspx page inline coding

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, reference, telemetry

I am getting the below error when I tired to refer the "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" in SharePoint layouts aspx page which doesn't has a code behind page.

> An error occurred during the compilation of the requested file, or one of its dependencies. The type or namespace name 'TelemetryClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tried the below methods

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"%>
```

and also

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" %>
```

Below the piece of inline C# code in aspx page where I am trying to crate TelemetryClient object to log data into Azure

```
.....
TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = instKey;
telemetryClient.TrackException(ex, sp_coid);
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" %>` is the right way to include namespace but still if you are getting error then *have you taken/added  reference of that dll `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` in your project?* (or) probably install from NuGet

Comment: It would refer from GAC on the server right? I am packaging the SharePoint wsp on local and deploying it on the server.